# Trim or strip spaces around the email or username on the login page

Tags: forms, 9, authentication-authorization

I know that my Drupal installation (9.3.15) doesn't trim spaces at the login page (form id: user-login-form).
I have some code in the `HOOK_form_user_login_form_alter` but in that place in `$form_state` I don't have any `->getValue('%field%')` , it returns NULL.
Also I can not modify '$form['name']['#value']' because it is empty in that context.

How do I trim spaces on the user's input? I can do `$form_state->getUserInput();` and I can see what the user has entered but I don't know how to modify it. Because $form_alter is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `your_module.module`

1. You create form alter if there is no any (e.g. `HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter()`)
2. you add a validation callback to a field of the whole form  (e.g. `array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'trim_login_credentials');`)
3. create `function trim_login_credentials(&$form, $form_state) {}`
4. add your validation or string operations into that the newly created function;

I do 'array_unshift()` because I want my validation *before* Drupal's.

[Another way](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2009-01-08/adding-extra-validation-to-user-login)

[A question at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190703/how-to-alter-the-drupal8-user-login-form-inputs-and-validation)

Comment: This doesn't answer the *I can do `$form_state->getUserInput();` and I can see what the user has entered but I don't know how to modify it.* part.

Comment: @apaderno apparently you don't do anything with that user input. It was the only place where you can see what a user has entered, but it has passed the validation at that stage so no matter what you do with $form_state - it's too late to trim spaces. In the beginning, I thought there is something I can do with it. The question is - how to trim spaces. And there are no good questions on the internet about this